# Parsing files with multiple lines of identical JSON code in Azure Logic Apps

Tags: json, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-logic-apps

In an Azure Logic App, I am parsing files with JSON code, and inserting the content in an SQL DB. This works very well, when my files have one line of code. To minimize the amount of files, I can add multiple lines in one file. The number of lines is not fixed, so it could be 1 or perhaps up to 50 lines.

I have tried to find a simple way to make the "For Each" logic do the task, but I can't quite figure out how it should be done.

This is an example of the contents of one of the files:

```
{
    "Real01": 200.1999969482422,
    "DINT01": 4500,
    "String01": "Some_text:  1435 2",
    "Bit01": false
}
{
    "Real01": 700.699951171875,
    "DINT01": 4505,
    "String01": "Some_text:  1435 2",
    "Bit01": false
}
{
    "Real01": 1201.1998291015625,
    "DINT01": 4510,
    "String01": "Some_text:  1435 2",
    "Bit01": false
}
{
    "Real01": 1701.69970703125,
    "DINT01": 4515,
    "String01": "Some_text:  1435 2",
    "Bit01": false
}
{
    "Real01": 2202.19970703125,
    "DINT01": 4520,
    "String01": "Some_text:  1435 2",
    "Bit01": false
}
{
    "Real01": 2702.7001953125,
    "DINT01": 4525,
    "String01": "Some_text:  1436 2",
    "Bit01": true
}
```

When I parse the file, only the first values (between the first `{` and `}`) are processed and inserted into the DB. I would appreciate if someone could help make it possible to insert all 6 lines in the DB.

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing is the expected behavior because the JSON in the Question is not valid JSON.

Multiple top level *objects* {} are not allowed.  Only 1 object or array [] is allowed.

The first step is to contact the creator of this output and have them correct their process to emit valid.

If they are unable or unwilling to correct their output, you next step is to inform your management that this is not a problem with you, your app or LogicApps.  The sender is producing invalid JSON.

Then, you need to fix the problem yourself by making that at least an array.

Example: [ {}, {}, {} ]

Note the square brackets and commas between the objects.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The supplied data source files are my own, and I have now managed to turn them into scalable, correctly formatted files, so that they now look like this:
`code`
[{
    "Real01": 33433.3203125,
    "DINT01": 21798,
    "String01": "Some_text:  123557",
    "Bit01": true
},{
    "Real01": 33933.828125,
    "DINT01": 21803,
    "String01": "Some_text:  123557",
    "Bit01": true
}
}]

Comment: ...
So far, so good.
Though I expected Azure to accept a JSON array and just willingly add each object into an SQL query and stuff them into my DB, I just get "InvalidTemplate. Unable to process template language expressions in action 'Execute_a_SQL_query' inputs at line '1' and column '2823': 'The template language expression 'body('Parse_JSON')['Real01']' cannot be evaluated because property 'Real01' cannot be selected. Array elements can only be selected using an integer index!

Answer (score 0):

The Logic Apps / Power Automate flow HTTP connector will only return one row if the response is in a newline-delimited JSON (NDJSON) or JSON Lines (JSONL) format. The HTTP connector has not been configured to read non standard JSON formats. As a result you will only receive 1 line in the response as there's no comma to delimit the JSON lines. Instead they're separated by line carriage returns.

If you don't have access to the JSON source data in order to change the format then you have to find an alternative to the HTTP connector. My solution was an Azure Powershell automation Runbook to return all the JSON lines and then manipulate the results in the Logic App using a variable with expressions.

To create the Runbook, first create an [automation account](https://portal.azure.com/#create/Microsoft.AutomationAccount) in Azure. Then create a Runbook under the Process Automation left menu header.

[image]

The Runbook will have the following code to fetch all the rows from your API / source and then output the results:

```
try
{
    $null = Connect-AzAccount -Identity
}
catch {
    Write-Error -Message $_.Exception
    throw $_.Exception
}

# Variables
$Uri = "https://api.myapilink.com/api/..."

$Header = @{ "content-type" = "application/json" }

$publishJSON = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $Uri -Headers $Header

Write-Output $publishJSON
```

In your Logic App / Flow add a Create Job Automation action and select your Runbook. Make sure to select Yes for the Wait for job field.

[image]

Then get the job output of your created job using the Get job output action:

[image]

Next create a string variable in your Logic app and assign the following expression from your job output to it:

```
[@{replace(body('Get_job_output'), '}\r\n{', '},{')}]
```

You'll need to change

> body('Get_job_output')

To the name of out output action. Also you will find that the Logic apps designer will remove the line break / escape characters i.e. \r\n from the expression. You'll need to go into the Logic apps code view and amend the expression to the above.

[image]

Now that you have the output in string format, you'll need to convert to JSON. Add a new Parse JSON data operation action and add the following expression to the content field:

```
json(variables('MyVariableNameFromAbove'))
```

Make sure to add the relevant schema of your JSON to the schema field. You should now see your response in the correct JSON format.